# repetition of the rows based on another column value when the data is on both nmureric and alpha thru python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like below.The data frame is to be modified based on the condition of the to field.

```
   <code>
      data from to
      abc  1     3
      bcd  1     4
      klm  T1    T4
      GKN  R123   R125
 </CODE>
```

The above data frame is to be expanded in sequence based on the to value. The out to be
something like

`data from to
abc  1     3
abc  2     3
abc  3     3
bcd  1     4
bcd  2     4
bcd  3     4
bcd  4     4
klm  T1    T4
klm  T2    T4
Klm  T3    T4
Klm  T4    T4
GKN  R123  R125
GKN  R124  R125
GKN  R125  R125`

I am able to get the data as expected when only numeric by using the below

`df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['to'] - df['from'] + 1)]
df['from'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + df['from']
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

But having the difficulty on char fields. Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you explain the repetition for rows `klm` and `GKN`?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the letters from the data in your dataframe and then reinsert the letters after applying the expansion.